# Simple svg not rendering an element

Tags: svg, rust, graphics

I am using the rust svg crate to render an svg and I am only getting one of 2 objects. The generated svg is this:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M20,20 l0,50 l50,0 l0,-50 z" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="3">
<path d="M10,30 l0,50 l50,0 l0,-50 z" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="3"/>
</path>
</svg>
```

I see this:
[image]

The other path  which is clearly computed at an offset is nowhere to be seen. What do I do?

Comment: I don't think nesting `path`s is supported by svg. That seems very odd. I'd tend to not expect anything of a render of non standard svg.

Comment: What would be the vlaid svg xml if we were to correc tthe above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot put a `path` inside another `path` since it's not [permitted content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/path). So your svg is invalid.
This would be valid instead:

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="M20,20 l0,50 l50,0 l0,-50 z" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="3"/>
  <path d="M10,30 l0,50 l50,0 l0,-50 z" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="3"/>
</svg>
```